# How to use SQLiteOpenHelper with fragments in Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I'm trying to implement a To-do list app into my app by using a Fragments instead of Activities. I ran into some issues I was able to fix, but now the activity is unable to start.

**TaskDbHelper**

```
class TaskDbHelper(fragment: HomeFragment) : SQLiteOpenHelper(fragment.requireContext(), TaskContract.DB_NAME, null, TaskContract.DB_VERSION) {

override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
    val createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE + " (" +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.ID + " INTEGER, " +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TEXT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

    db.execSQL(createTable)
}

override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE)
    onCreate(db)
}
```

}

I changed the parameters from `context:` to `fragments:` and `fragment.requireContext()`, in the helper.

**This is what the log says**

```
  Process: com.khumomashapa.notes, PID: 15097
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.khumomashapa.notes/com.khumomashapa.notes.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HomeFragment{1c275a3} (14bd8ea4-7821-4630-9a9a-c93eaaa2e0d5)} not attached to a context.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3654)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3806)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2267)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8167)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HomeFragment{1c275a3} (14bd8ea4-7821-4630-9a9a-c93eaaa2e0d5)} not attached to a context.
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireContext(Fragment.java:805)
        at com.khumomashapa.notes.sql.TaskDbHelper.<init>(TaskDbHelper.kt:10)
        at com.khumomashapa.notes.fragments.HomeFragment.<init>(HomeFragment.kt:25)
        at com.khumomashapa.notes.activities.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:33)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7963)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7952)
```

When someone starts my app, the Home Fragment is the first one they are supposed to see, but it crashes immediately.

**Here's the Home Fragment, but only the lines that cause the exception**

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private var mHelper: TaskDbHelper = TaskDbHelper(this)
    private val adapter = MyAdapter(this, mHelper)
    private val TAG: String = "HomeFragment"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initialising `TaskDbHelper` before your fragment gets attached to an activity. You need to make sure you're accessing context/view related things in the correct points in your fragments lifecycle which you can read more about [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle).

Generally you should perform any view related logic in `onViewCreated` and accessing context can be done even earlier, most likely in `onAttached`.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `homefragment.requireContext()` before the Fragment is properly initialised. See [Fragment Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle)

You could solve this by making mHelper a `lateinit var` and filling it in an appropiate callback, e.g.

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    mHelper = TaskDbHelper(this)
}
```

... but thats a quick & dirty solution. Personally i would most probably look into dependency-injection...